# Database Projects in Visual Studio 2015 against SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2016

I am experimenting with SQL Server 2016 (RTC 3) for a personal project . I am trying to create a database project in Visual Studio 2015 and connect to the database. I can successfully create a connection to my database, but when I use the "Import Database" and click "Start", I get an error "Could not connect to the database to retrieve the configuration.

I don't know if this is due to my trying to use SQL Server 2016, but at this point since it has been released for review I would think VS 2015 could handle it.

Any insights would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) the new (March 7 2016) preview release of SQL Server data tools adds support for SQL Server 2016, and the current stable version only goes to SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server data tools in Visual Studio only support SQL Server till version 2014, because of which this error is getting generated. Using VS2017 you can get rid of this error, as VS2017 support SQL Server16 as well.